# ImageMagic renders image with black background

Tags: linux, imagemagick-convert

I'm converting pdf files to images with ImageMagic, everything is ok until I use `-resize` option, then I get image with black background. I use this command:

```
convert -density 400 image.pdf -resize 25% image.png
```

I need to use `-resize` option otherwise I get really large image. Is there any other option which I can use to resize image or is there option to set background in white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing alpha from image, it seems imagemagic tries to apply some opacity but since jpeg doesn't allow transperency result was black background. So I found example on imagemagic website and it helped me:

```
convert a.pdf   -background skyblue  -alpha remove -alpha off a_remove.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Ghostscript command, You will need to find out what convert is sending to Ghostscript. As it stands I can't even be sure that your problem is with Ghostscript ,since it could easily be something that convert is doing.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it's ghostscript, can you tell me how to check what convert is sending to ghostscript

Comment: I updatated my question, I'm using imagemagic not ghostscript